# Python/Django: Cómo manejar información recibida de un form? input

Tags: python, django, django-forms

estoy aprendiendo django y el view que estoy escribiendo no parece aceptar el input dado por el usuario en el form.

Estoy construyendo un proyecto personal para una Sala de ensayos. Las bandas reservan su espacio y pueden acceder a cierta información. Una de las funcionalidades es ver las reservaciones hechas en un fecha específica. Lo que quiero es *mostrar solamente las reservas específicas de un día, sin importar qué usuario realizó la reserva*.

Tengo la impresión de que el problema reside en esta línea de código `form = CheckReservationForm(request.POST or None)` en mi `views.py`.

Algo que intenté con éxito fue obtener el QuerySet que buscaba desde el Shell de esta manera:

```
>>from .forms import CheckReservationForm
>>from .models import Reserva

>>data = {'date': '2020-12-24'} #el teórico input del usuario
>>form = CheckReservationForm(data) #inicializo el form con el input
```

Luego de eso solamente validé el input con `form.is_valid()` y me retornó `True`. Y leí por ahí que una vez que el form es válido, se puede acceder a su "clean data". Entonces tiré:

```
>>cd = form.cleaned_data['date']
>>r_list = Reserva.objects.filter(date=cd)
```

y al ejecutar `r_list` me da un QuerySet con las reservaciones correctas para el 24 de diciembre.

Ahora, no estoy siendo capaz de trasladar esta lógica a mis archivos de Python. A continuación les dejo los archivos principales. Cualquier pista o ayuda es inmensamente valiosa! Gracias.

models.py

```
class Reserva(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    check_in = models.TimeField()
    check_out = models.TimeField()

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='reservation')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class CheckReservationForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(label="Date")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Reserva
from .forms import CheckReservationForm

def availability(request):
    form = CheckReservationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data['date']
            reservas = Reserva.objects.filter(date=cd)
            context = {
                'reservas': reservas,
            }
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app/daylist.html', context))
    return render(request, 'app/res_form.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views as app_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', app_views.index, name="index"),
    path('reservas/', app_views.reservas, name='reservas'),
    path('reservas/availability/', app_views.availability, name='availability'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

espero el sitio te este siendo de ayuda, lo primero que te sugiero que hagas para ver si el form es valido o no es que le agregues un else e imprimas form.errors, si es error de validación se vera ahí. Se utiliza el cleaned_data ya que este te devuelve la información después de pasar la validación o un ValidationError en caso contrario. Si quieres acceder directamente a la información del request.POST lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
fecha = request.POST.get('date', None)
```

Esta instrucción te almacenara la fecha si existe en el request.POST de caso contrario te almacenara un None.

Se pone el request.POST or None ya que en caso de recibir información por el método request.POST se pasa el data al formulario, en caso de no recibir el request.POST se le pasa un None al data del formulario.

Implementando similarmente a lo que pones, puedes ver si es un error de validación de esta manera:

```
    form = CheckReservationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request == 'POST':
       print('datos del post:', request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            fecha = form.cleaned_data['date']
            reservas = Reserva.objects.filter(date=fecha)
            print('reservas:', reservas)
            context = {
                'reservas': reservas,
            }
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app/daylist.html', context))
        else:
            print('errores del form: ', form.errors)

    return render(request, 'app/res_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Recuerda que los print te pueden ir ayudando a revisar parte por parte tu código mientras sigues aprendiendo, posteriormente puedes usar el Debug para ir observando la ejecución linea por linea y observando como lleva a cabo el proceso de creación, asignación de variables, etc.

Comment: Gracias @Kevin, logré que funcionara! Aunque tuve que modificarle también el `HttpResponseRedirect` por una función `render`. Tendré que revisar la documentación sobre cómo manejar ese return. En fin, te agradezco mucho los consejos y el ir imprimiendo en consola me ayudó mucho a entender qué era lo que estaba haciendo mal. Gracias de nuevo.